# Bad performance on SQL server (express) because of indexed view

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL server express 2017 with an indexed view (clustered index) to speed up database reading. When we insert/alter data which will change the view, the query runs "for ever" (even longer then creating the whole index) but there is no usage of CPU on the server. If we remove the index, the query finish in less then 1 second.
[image]

I have also compared the time to create the index on the express version and on an enterprise version of sql server 2017. The index creation uses 1/3 of the time on the enterprise version, even its running on a 5 year old laptop. The CPU on the laptop will be used 100%. When I create the index on the express edition (on a server with more cores, more memory and faster disks) there is no use of cpu, memory or disk activity.

So the question is, is this because the express edition will limit the use of CPU and disk (as it does with memory, which is max ~1,5 gb)?

Comment: Can you add the execution plans for the query on both servers? Can you post the output of select * from sys.configurations;? Are both servers using parallelism?

Comment: I could show the execution plan, but its really huge, so dont think it would help that much. Both servers use default  settings (Max degree of Parallelism: 0)

Comment: You can add the plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I haven't seen anything that limits the disk of Express, CPU is limited to 4 cores and memory is limited to 1410MB. I'd assume it's the CPU / memory limitations personally. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-editions But the best method is to measure and compare using wait statistics and query plans.